# Draggable div collision with moving circles

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to change my speed circles from low to high and alert when my square div crash wit circles
but i dont know how to do it 
it is sort of game you must avoid from crashin with circles
if crashed alert you lose
this is my code

```
$(function()
{
function randomNum(max)
{
    var num = Math.ceil(Math.random()*max);
    return num;
};
function randomcolor()
{
    var r = randomNum(255);
    var g = randomNum(255);
    var b = randomNum(255);
    var color = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
    return color;
};
function makeNewPosition()
{

// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $(window).height() - 50;
var w = $(window).width() - 50;

var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

return [nh,nw];    

};

animateDiv();



function animateDiv(){
 $('.abi').each(function() {
 var newq = makeNewPosition();
 var oldq = $(this).offset();
 var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
 $(this).css('background-color', randomcolor());
 $(this).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed,function(){ animateDiv(); });

 });

};



function calcSpeed(prev, next) 
{

var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

var speedModifier = 0.1;

var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

return speed;
};
});
function endMove() {
$(this).removeClass('movable');
}
  function startMove() {
   $('.movable').on('mousemove', function(event) {
  var thisX = event.pageX - $(this).width() / 2,
      thisY = event.pageY - $(this).height() / 2;

   $('.movable').offset({
    left: thisX,
    top: thisY
  });
});
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#containerDiv").on('mousedown', function() {
$(this).addClass('movable');
startMove();
}).on('mouseup', function() {
$(this).removeClass('movable');
endMove();
 });

 });
```

Comment: this my full codes in jseditfile http://jsfiddle.net/3Hfwn/

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery… http://jsfiddle.net/3Hfwn/1/

Comment: oh yeah thnx for that i confused youknow wh at am i doing for changing speed and alerting crash? please guide me